# Authorization required for downloading

Tags: pdf, download, authorization, protected

i want to download a book from :

https://digimaze.org/api/storage/v1/books/212/file

but ( [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYidD.png) ) occurs

anybody know how can i download this file?

this books are protected and monitoring with MuPDF , anybody knows that how can i download .PDF files?